# How do I strip commas, brackets in shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

okay so after a lot of searching i decided to ask the question i've tried doing print[0] but i got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in 
    print[0]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

```
 ['a', 'c', 'e']
[1, 3, 5]
```

these are my 2 outputs i want to remove the commas and the inverted commas and make it look like

```
ace
135
```

Answer (score 0):

For list with `str`:

```
x = ['a','c','e']
str1 = ''.join(x)
```

For list with `int`:

```
x = [1,2,3]
str1=''.join(str(y) for y in x)
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(a)
print ''.join(a)
```

And for the integer list [1,3,5] first change elements to strings using:

```
map(lambda x: str(x), [1,3,5])
```

and then issue the same line as the first. Then you can change back to int if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To create a string from list's elements:

```
my_list_1 = ['a', 'c', 'e']
my_list_2 = [1, 3, 5]

# The "join" works for both when list's element type is "string" or "int"
list_1_str = ''.join(map(str, my_list_1))
# output: "ace"

list_2_str = ''.join(map(str, my_list_2))
# output: "135"
```